# How to calculate Q1, Q2... but for a given date and not 01 Jan

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been trying to calculate the Quarter period but not for a year that starts on 01 Jan but for a date that denotes the end of year which could be 03-22 for example.

There are a lot of examples on how to do Q1, Q2 but none I can find or can develop which I have been trying to do for days now.

> The input will be:
>
> 1. Current Date
> 2. Frequency (months)
>
> **3. Tax end (Month & Day)**
>
> For the inputs
>
> 1. Current Date > 2018-02-01
> 2. Frequency (months) 3
>
> **3. Tax end (Month & Day)** 12-31
>
> Result
>
> *Current quarter* start=2018-01-01 end  =2018-03-31
>
> *Last Quarter* start=2017-01-10 end  =2017-31-12

The closest I can get is [Google Spread Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLnwamjjlfidKCOp2O57xtv3tRA1xN3Pb7UYR6P__Dc/edit?usp=sharing) which can be copied but it breaks down when it stretches over years.

The closest I have got is:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A5),FLOOR(MONTH(A5)-MONTH(G5),E5)+1,DAY(G5))
```

Where 
A5=current date
G5=period in months. 
E5=Tax Filing date (I.e end period) + 1 would give you start period.

I just can't figure it out or even if it is possible in a formula.

Comment: Your attached sample file link is not public.. can't xs the file. error : "Need to request permission"..

Comment: I've re-read the question 4 times now and still not sure what you're asking :) Do you want quarter start dates from any given date? If so use DateAdd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

[image]

Here are the formulas:

```
$C$4:     =EDATE(DATE(YEAR([@[Current Date]]),MONTH(EndOfYear),DAY(EndOfYear)+1),CHOOSE(MATCH([@[Current Date]],EDATE(EndOfYear,{-12,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12})),-12,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12))
$D$4:     =EDATE([@[Current Quarter start]]-1,3)
$E$4:     =EDATE([@[Current Quarter start]],-3)
$F$4:     =[@[Current Quarter start]]-1
```

`EndOfYear` is a normal date.  In the formula in `C4`, we normalize it to refer to a year relative to `Current Date`, thereby getting around the multiyear issue.

There is an assumption that `EndOfYear` will not be on `29-Feb`, otherwise the results may be unexpected.

Note that in your example, your date formats are inconsistent.  I have formatted the dates in my example with the months spelled out so as to be unambiguous.

Since you are looking for Quarters, the `Frequency (months)` column is ignored.